# A feature definition could not be found for usr:arquillian-support-1.0

Tags: jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

Liberty 20.0.0.1/AdoptOpenJdk 8

```sh
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Liberty Arquillian 1.0.6(liberty-managed) server.xml config.

```xml
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
        <feature>usr:arquillian-support-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

When I have add `usr:arquillian-support-1.0` feature to *server.xml* and start the application server and got the error info like this.

```sh
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for usr:arquillian-support-1.0
```

The sample project is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arquillian support feature is only needed to correctly report the exception that occurred when a test app failed to start, so depending on what you're testing, you may not need it at all.

If you do need it, the feature itself is distributed as a zip file which just needs extracted into your liberty server. You can configure your pom.xml to extract it as part of your build using `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>extract-support-feature</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <artifactItems>
      <artifactItem>
        <groupId>io.openliberty.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-liberty-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <classifier>feature</classifier>
        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/liberty/wlp/usr</outputDirectory>
      </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Example taken from: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/liberty-arquillian/tree/master/liberty-support-feature

Looking at your sample project, it looks like you're already using the maven-dependecy-plugin to deploy the derby jar, so you may need to adapt this example a bit to make it work.

I *think* you will want to move the `<configuration>` blocks inside the `<execution>` blocks, so that each execution has a separate configuration, and then include both `<execution>` blocks inside the same `<plugin>` block, but I'm not terribly confident with maven.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible right now to use the usr:arquillian-support-1.0 feature with Open Liberty. There are two parts to this.

The open liberty distribution you are using doesn't include the arquillian support feature. There is nothing in the pom.xml that would enable it to work. The Liberty maven plugin does have some support for installing extra features, however it doesn't (at this time) work with usr features such as the arquillian-support-1.0 feature. I think that is being tracked by this [issue](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/9227) in GitHub.

So for now I'd just remove that line from the server.xml. I'd also suggest looking at the liberty-maven-plugin, I think it can significantly simplify the maven configuration you are doing to get Liberty working, and when support for usr features is added you'll need it to get arquillian-support-1.0 added.

Comment: Is it possible to add the dependencies in pom.xml or package it into `liberty-managed` to make it work? When using liberty arquillian I really do not want to use liberty maven plugin to handle these to make things complex.

Comment: The Liberty maven plugin is the thing that adds that capability, although as I said not for usr features.